How to use SegFormer encoder and decoder separately?
I am trying to understand SegFormer model, and would like to use encoder and decoder separately with different models.
I have tried looking into official implementation which is based on mmseg and also checked transformers based HuggingFace usage, but I don't understand how to separate encoder and decoder section.
How can I use different components of the model from HuggingFace or official implementation; and use it?

Do you want to use the pre-trained weights?

Ideally I would like to use pretrained weights with encoder part, and for decoder with other models I would not like to use pretrained weights.

To initialize the encoder with pre-trained weights, you can use the SegformerModel class with the from_pretrained method:
from transformers import SegformerModel

m = SegformerModel.from_pretrained("nvidia/mit-b0")

To initialize the decoder, you can pass a SegformerConfig object to the SegformerDecodeHead class:
from transformers import SegformerConfig, SegformerDecodeHead

c = SegformerConfig()
d = SegformerDecodeHead(c)

The SegformerConfig object holds all the parameters to define the decoder layers. You can modify the parameters as properties: c.decoder_hidden_size = 32.

This helps.How to use segformer decoder with other encoder? Do I pass SegformerConfig()or use other model encoder confg and pass it to segformer decoder? And how to ensure the training is done smoothly other encoder+segformer decoder?

@Deep Your questions are too broad. You can simply check the source of the decoder and see that you need to pass the hidden_states of an encoder: code.

Sure, I will look into the source code and come back with any specific comment or question
